# Can't parse parameters from POST Request's JSON body

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net core MVC Controller with the following method

```
[HttpPost("MyMethod")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestMethod([FromBody] string[] IDs)
{
    // ...
}
```

I'm trying to call this method via a POST Request with body:

```
{"IDs":["Test1", "Test2"]}
```

however, when the method is called, IDs is null. In my logs, I see an entry "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter - JSON input formatter threw an exception.", which I would assume is related to this.

What am I doing wrong here?
Do I need to somehow modify my C# method's signature for it to parse the request's body correctly? Or does the request's body need to look different in order to be readible by the server?

__

edit: The full JSON exception in C# seems to be:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.String[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'IDs', line 1, position 9.

---

probably not relevant for the question, but I'm submitting the POST Request via VBA-Tools for Excel:

```
Dim Client As New WebClient
Client.BaseUrl = ' ... url to the request

Dim Request As New WebRequest

Request.Method = WebMethod.HttpPost
Request.RequestFormat = JSON
Call Request.AddBodyParameter("IDs", someStringArray)

Dim response As WebResponse
Client.TimeoutMs = 120000
Set response = Client.Execute(Request)
```

Comment: you perhaps need to add a content-type header to your request to inform MVC that you're sending JSON, otherwise it'll assume you're sending standard form-urlencoded data. Also if you're planning to create an endpoint to be called by other applications you might be better off creating a Web API controller for this purpose instead of an MVC controller.

Comment: Thanks for the WebController hint, I'll take a look into this. As for JSON - I have tried specifying this explicitly (from what I can tell, unless VBA-Tools did something odd; see Request.RequestFormat = JSON); given there is a Json serialization exception, I would assume the server is already trying to interpret the body as JSON though?

Comment: Can you send the full request? like with fiddler

Comment: The error is telling what's wrong, and indeed how to fix it; you're passing an object instead of an array. Just pass `["Test1","Test2"]` as the body.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks, you're right. Seems difficult (impossible?) to use if the C# function has multiple parameters. Maybe I'll have to create a container type so that the function accepts 1 parameter only

Comment: @Bogey that's the common design yes - the concept is called creating a ViewModel